# Terms aggregation returns enormous invalid values

Tags: elasticsearch

when using ES 1.7.2 a terms aggregation top-20 list of terms contains values such as 4639024275540410000 when the actual highest values is 199.

I wonder if this is a known issue with 1.7.2 and we should migrate to a new release?

Here's the offending query:

```
GET metrics-2016-04/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "jvm.thread-states.count"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result contains these enormous values:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 16,
      "successful": 16,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 9394,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "3": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 1511,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 50,
               "doc_count": 1376
            },
            {
               "key": 138,
               "doc_count": 1344
            },
            {
               "key": 137,
               "doc_count": 1299
            },
            {
               "key": 144,
               "doc_count": 681
            },
            {
               "key": 143,
               "doc_count": 649
            },
            {
               "key": 141,
               "doc_count": 611
            },
            {
               "key": 142,
               "doc_count": 603
            },
            {
               "key": 4639024275540410000,
               "doc_count": 448
            },
            {
               "key": 4632233691727266000,
               "doc_count": 445
            },
            {
               "key": 4639059459912499000,
               "doc_count": 427
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

When I perform a regular bool query with a range condition for the highest value, I get exactly the one result but definitely nothing higher.

Query:

```
GET metrics-2016-04/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gte": 199,
              "lte": 1000000000000000000000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "jvm.thread-states.count"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": ["value"]
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 12,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 16,
      "successful": 16,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 5.197636,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRivuU1roeuo1W0WbLL",
            "_score": 5.197636,
            "fields": {
               "value": [
                  199
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

UPDATE: When I perform a range query to find these high values, I seem to get regular smaller values around 100:

```
GET metrics-2016-04/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gte":  9999999999999999999999999999999
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "jvm.thread-states.count"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 16,
      "successful": 16,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 9394,
      "max_score": 5.206709,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRhsQLjroeuo1W0WVJG",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T11:04:31.000+0000",
               "value": 105
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRhstejroeuo1W0WVLI",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T11:06:31.000+0000",
               "value": 104
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRhxScEroeuo1W0WVfb",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T11:26:31.000+0000",
               "value": 104
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRh5L9qroeuo1W0WV-S",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T12:01:01.000+0000",
               "value": 104,
               "instance_name": "mainline"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRh_mHAroeuo1W0WWat",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T12:29:01.000+0000",
               "value": 105,
               "instance_name": "mainline"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRiZMljroeuo1W0WW4h",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T14:20:52.000+0000",
               "value": 101,
               "instance_name": "HAJNM2110001.local"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRii6Lfroeuo1W0WXjM",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T15:03:18.000+0000",
               "value": 138,
               "instance_name": "lx220-itest-mainline-destimo3-s1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRij0xcroeuo1W0WXun",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T15:07:18.000+0000",
               "value": 138,
               "instance_name": "lx220-itest-mainline-destimo3-s1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRiknbnroeuo1W0WX4K",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T15:10:46.000+0000",
               "value": 50,
               "instance_name": "vlx0366-destimo-mainline"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "metrics-2016-04",
            "_type": "gauge",
            "_id": "AVRilYAXroeuo1W0WYEd",
            "_score": 5.206709,
            "_source": {
               "name": "jvm.thread-states.count",
               "@timestamp": "2016-04-29T15:14:05.000+0000",
               "value": 95,
               "instance_name": "HAJN72110657"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `top_hits` to get one of those documents back (the complete document): `"aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: @AndreiStefan Nice idea, but 'top_hits' only returns the best matching documents sorted by their score and you can't sort by their count.

I've tried a range query with the same idea (see the update) in mind to find the original documents but their values are just low regular numbers...

Comment: I see your search request is for the entire index, without specific types (`GET metrics-2016-04/_search`). Can you try the same but narrowing down on the type itself? `GET metrics-2016-04/gauge/_search`

Comment: @AndreiStefan Unfortunately that returns the same result. Interestingly the new month's index 2016-05 doesn't experience this problem at all. For now I think this could have happened because I added some fields to this type after creating it. The two requests GET metrics-2016-04/_mappings and GET metrics-2016-05/_mappings return the same mapping though.

Comment: _I added some fields to this type after creating it._ <- can you reproduce that with a clean index?

Comment: Can you try something else? Call `POST /_cache/clear?fielddata=true&index=metrics-2016-04` to clear fielddata cache just for that index. Then call your aggregation again.

Comment: @AndreiStefan hmm, maybe I could reproduce it. Clearing the cache didn't change the result.

Comment: :-) then I'm out of ideas. If you can reproduce it, that would be great.